# Regular expression is need to change URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to convert these URLs to SEO friendly URLs:

```
index.php?t=1&s=1&offset=50&hits=50   --->  index-t-1-s-1-offset-50-hits-50.html
index.php?t=1&s=1                     --->  index-t-1-s-1.html
index.php?t=1&s=&offset=50&hits=50    --->  index-t-1-s-1-offset-50-hits-50.html
index.php?t=1                         --->  index-t-1.html
```

I have written this:

```
$filename = substr(basename($base_href),0,'-4');
$str = preg_replace('/href=\'\?t=(\d+)&s=(\d+)\'/i', 'href=\''.$filename.'-t-$1-s-$2.html\'', $str);
```

but I need a universal expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that you replaced the `.php?` (`?` I think that is optional) term and all simbols to `-`, appending `.html` in the end. So, you just need do that:

```
$filename = "index.php?t=1&s=1&offset=50&hits=50";
$result = preg_replace('/(?:\.php\??|\W)/', '-', $filename) . '.html';
//~> index-t-1-s-1-offset-50-hits-50.html
```

It'll do:

- Replace `.php?` or `.php` to `-`;
- Replace not-letters `\W` (not confuse with `\w`) to `-`;
- Append `.html` on result

Read more about regular expression [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html/)

Answer (score 0):

For the solution, I would first split the URL by `?`, then replace all `&` and `=` with `-`, and concatenate the string back (after processing to remove `.php` in the other part of the URL)